# How to Prefill a Foundry Form embedded in a Slate document (using handlebars)?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I am trying to prefill a form embedded in a Slate document but without success.
The format bellow seems not to work:
"prefilledValues": {"uri_name1":"prefilledvalue1","uri_name2":"prefilledvalue1"...}
Furthermore, can we use Handlebars to prefill a form?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to setup your Form correctly to make it prefillable. Open the form, select an element that you want to prefill and choose "Configure field".

[image: configure field]

This will open the Properties-panel on the right side of your form. On the bottom of the Properties select "Advanced". Then a field called "UrlParam" will be displayed. This is where you set the parameter name that you will later call in Slate for prefilling. In my example I set it to "Threshold".

[image: url param]

In Slate, add a Foundry Form-widget and set the Form RID to the RID of your Form. Now you should be able to successfully add a prefilled value using the UrlParam that you set in the Form like this:

[image: prefilled values]

Now you should see that the embedded Form in Slate is displaying your prefilled value:

[image: result]

And yes, Handlebars can be used to prefill a form, but it seems like that it only accepts strings. So if you have a numeric value, make sure to convert it to String with the helper-function toString, for example if you have a variable called v_test with a value of 4:

[image: prefilled values with handlebars]

That should lead to this result:

[image: result with handlebars]